# Why can't I use webrick with git instaweb on Mac OS X?

Tags: git, macos

I'm trying to use `git instaweb` with Ruby' webrick (which I have installed) on Mac OS X, but every time I fire up

```
$ git instaweb --httpd=webrick
```

I get the following error:

> webrick not found. Install webrick or use --httpd to specify another httpd daemon.

Like I said, I *do* have webrick, so I don't know why `git instaweb` won't use it. Any ideas?

I'm using Git v1.7.2.1 on Mac OS X 10.6.

Comment: Try to ask on git mailing list `git@vger.kernel.org` (you don't need to be subscribed to post), cc-ing Eric Wong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `webrick` server is fairly unique in that [git instaweb](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob;hb=HEAD;f=git-instaweb.sh) creates shell script named `webrick` in '$GIT_DIR/gitweb/', which runs '$GIT_DIR/gitweb/webrick.rb', which in turn has `require 'webrick'` as its first line.  Check if those generated files are there, and that thye call files that exist.

'$GIT_DIR' is `.git` in top directory of your project, or just `git rev-parse --git-dir`.

Comment: There's no `webrick` rile in `.git/gitweb`. `.git/gitweb` only contains two files: `gitweb_config.perl` and a `tmp` directory that is empty.

Comment: Ah, I see, this is a bug in `git instaweb` introduced by 'be5347b (git-instaweb: Put httpd logs in a "$httpd_only" subdirectory, 2010-05-28)', first appearing in git version 1.7.2.  This commit changed order of generating config and checking if requested web server is available, which screws things up for webrick.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `git config --global instaweb.httpd "webrick"`. Then when you type `git instaweb` it will use webrick by default.

I found this out with a lucky guess - it's not documented anywhere I could find.